# Defining the action of elliptic curve $E$ on a principal homogeneous space of $E$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I recently learnt (using Milne's book about elliptic curves) about principal homogeneous space for elliptic curves. For completeness I state the definition here: Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $k$. A principal homogeneous space for $E$ is a curve $W$ over $k$ together with a right action of $E$ given by a regular map $W\times E \to W$ via
$$ (w, P) \mapsto w + P $$
such that
$$ (w, P) \mapsto (w, w + P) : W \times E \to W \times W $$
is an isomorphism of algebraic varieties.

Then there are a few theorems about these PH spaces and basically the PH spaces are the twists of $E$. However, if I have a twist $E'$ of $E$, I am a bit confused as to how $E$ acts on $E'$.

I thought of a simple example for this: Let $k = \mathbb{Q}$ and
$$ E: y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$$
$$ E': y^2 = x^3 + 4 a x + 8 b $$
and then $\phi : E' \to E$ by
$$ \phi(x,y) = (\frac{x}{2}, \frac{y}{2 \sqrt 2}) $$
is an isomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$.

To define the action of $E$ on $E'$, the obvious way to me is as follows: If $P$ is a point on $E$, and $P'$ a point on $E'$, then we can define $P' + P = P' + \phi^{-1}(P)$.

However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. For example, if $P' = O'$ (where $O'$ is the identity point of $E'$) then this formulas gives $O' + P = O' + \phi^{-1}(P) = \phi^{-1}(P)$. But $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are not neccessarily given by polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\phi^{-1}(P)$ might not be in $E'(\mathbb{Q})$, which means this does not give an action on $E'(\mathbb{Q})$. Which would mean that the way I tried to define the action is wrong.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E'/K$ be a twist of an elliptic curve $E/K$, we want to equip $E'$ with the structure of a principal homogeneous space for $E/K$ (FYI, you will also often see these called $K$-torsors for $(E, +)$ for extra jargon points). The structure you are looking for is not quite what you have written down, but it should appear in the results that are proven in the book.

Long story short, you have defined your action wrong, you're after: Fix an isomorphism $\phi : E' \to E$ over $\bar{K}$. Given $P' \in E'$ and $P \in E$  we define
$$ P' + P = \phi^{-1}(\phi(P') + P)$$
hence as you were worried about $P' + O = \phi^{-1}(\phi(P') + O) = P'$.

For $\sigma \in G_K$, let $\phi^{\sigma} = \sigma \phi \sigma^{-1}$ (you can also view this as $\sigma$ acting on the coefficients of $\phi$.

To see that the action is defined over $K$ notice that $\phi^{\sigma}\phi^{-1}$ is a translation on $E$, by say $Q_\sigma$. So that $\phi^{\sigma}(R) = \phi(R) + Q_\sigma$ for $R \in E'$.
\begin{align*}
\sigma(P' + P) &= (\phi^{-1})^{\sigma}(\sigma(\phi(P') + P)) \\
&= (\phi^{-1})^{\sigma}(\phi^\sigma (\sigma(P')) + \sigma(P)) \\
&= (\phi^{-1})^{\sigma}(\phi(\sigma(P')) + Q_\sigma  + \sigma(P)) \\
&= (\phi^{-1})(\phi(\sigma(P')) + \sigma(P)) \\
&= \sigma(P') + \sigma(P)
\end{align*}

---

The more general idea is as follows, for an object $X/K$ let $Y/K$ be a twist and fix $\phi : Y \to X$ an isomorphism over $\bar{K}$. Then $\xi_\sigma =  \phi^{\sigma}\phi^{-1}$ defines an injection $Twist(X/K) \to H^1(K, Aut(X))$ - when $X = E$ is a smooth projective curve this is a bijection (Silverman X Thrm 2.2) (it is actually true for any quasiprojective variety).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have a couple of questions. Isn't your definition of the action the same as mine? Since $\phi^{-1}(\phi(P') + P) = \phi^{-1} \phi (P') + \phi^{-1}(P) = P' + \phi^{-1}(P)$.

Comment: 2. Could you clarify what is the meaning of $\phi^\sigma$?

Comment: @eatfood to your second question, I have edited my answer. For your first question I tend to agree, although it is causing me to question many things - I'll get back to it

Comment: I think I have figured out the answer to my comment above, i.e. why we cannot distribute the $\phi^{-1}$ over the sum in the first equality. The reason is because $\phi$ is an isomorphism of algebraic curves, and not of elliptic curves, i.e. it does not have to respect the addition of points.

Comment: Another thing I realized while reading SIlverman's book closely is that my assumptions in the question is wrong. I made the claim that any twist of $E$ can be made into a principal homogenous space, but this is not true (i think). As you pointed out above, the set of twists of $E$ is in bijection with $H^1(K, Aut(E))$, but furthermore Silverman shows that the set of PH-spaces $WC(E/K)$ is in bijection with $H^1(K, E)$, and the two cohomology groups are definitely not equal.

Comment: @eatfood there is an isomorphism of groups $E \cong Aut(E)$ by taking $P$ to the translation by $P$ map. This is a bijection since an morphism is a composition of an isogeny and a translation. And yes sorry i never came back to this but that is the reason.